# How to get time difference from the first row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
rank                                               name           BIN                                            address                dateApply          col1_converetd
1                    1  "TechEngineering\n(ТехИнжиниринг)"\nжауапкерші...  190240019996  Мекен-жайы: Казахстан, 591010000, 150000, Севе...  05.01.2021 12:22:30.326 2021-01-05 12:22:30.326
2                    2                                   "Бестау - С" ЖШС  061240009707  Мекен-жайы: Казахстан, 551010000, 140000, Павл...  08.01.2021 20:51:20.473 2021-01-08 20:51:20.473
3                    3                                     "TN stroy" ЖШС  100240019523  Мекен-жайы: Казахстан, 191010000, 040000, Алма...  12.01.2021 16:06:45.699 2021-01-12 16:06:45.699
4                    4                           "Баспана-Қызылорда"\nЖШС  081140002165  Мекен-жайы: Казахстан, 431010000, 120014, Кызы...  13.01.2021 12:55:28.048 2021-01-13 12:55:28.048
5                    5         "Astana Technical\nSupervision Group"\nЖШС  120440012894  Мекен-жайы: Казахстан, 710000000, 010000, г.Ну...  13.01.2021 15:33:28.762 2021-01-13 15:33:28.762
6                    6                                     "ТЛГ 2002" ЖШС  021040005115  Мекен-жайы: Казахстан, 391010000, 110000, Кост...  14.01.2021 11:19:33.078 2021-01-14 11:19:33.078
7                    7  "СТРОЙИНТЕГРАЦИ\nЯ" құрылушы\nмекемелер\nдирек...  080340021473  Мекен-жайы: Казахстан, 116651100, 010022, Акмо...  14.01.2021 14:44:24.879 2021-01-14 14:44:24.879
8                    8                      "Компания Құрылыс\nкөмек" ЖШС  050240005195  Мекен-жайы: КАЗАХСТАН, 751310000, 50062, г.Алм...  18.01.2021 10:20:21.525 2021-01-18 10:20:21.525
9                    9  "VostokExpert"\nжауапкершілігі\nшектеулі серік...  200240015571  Мекен-жайы: Казахстан, 631010000, 070012, Вост...  18.01.2021 17:03:32.827 2021-01-18 17:03:32.827
10   10 "АДС САПА" ЖШС                                                     120940002382  Мекен-жайы: Казахстан, 710000000, 010000, г.Ну...  19.01.2021 12:18:19.951 2021-01-19 12:18:19.951
11     11 "Алатау сапа                                       құрылыс" ЖШС  050140003046  Мекен-жайы: Казахстан, 750000000, 050009, г.Ал...  19.01.2021 13:35:15.771 2021-01-19 13:35:15.771
12       12 "DS&V" ЖШС                                                     050140000110  Мекен-жайы: КАЗАХСТАН, 393243100, 110105, Кост...  19.01.2021 13:49:08.381 2021-01-19 13:49:08.381
13  13 "Инжиниринговая                              компания "Лидер"\nЖШС  110940004909  Мекен-жайы: Казахстан, 710000000, Z05P7T0, г.Н...  20.01.2021 11:38:46.802 2021-01-20 11:38:46.802
```

how can I get the time difference between the first row and others? first_row - second, first_row- third, etc

I have tried `df1['delta'] = (df1['col1_converetd'][0] - df1['col1_converetd'].shift())`

but this resulted in me difference between the preceding row.

Answer (score 2):

Seelct first value and subtract column:

```
df1['delta'] = df1['col1_converetd'].iat[0] - df1['col1_converetd']
```

Or subtract from right side by [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html):

```
df1['delta'] = df1['col1_converetd'].rsub(df1['col1_converetd'].iat[0])
```

Comment: Why `iat` instead of `iloc`?

Comment: @Learningisamess - it is faster, but used only for scalar ouput like here. iloc is possible use also for slices, more general, slowier ;)

Comment: Thanks @jezrael I did not know about it, have been using iloc everywhere. Will think of iat now for free speed up.